# Feedback form using extjs

Tags: extjs

[image: Feedback form demo]

I want to create a feedback form using extjs. How to align the button at side of screen. Kinda like the one in the photo. It is  snippet of dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This is a floating button.   Adjust the position and shape.

```
 var body = Ext.getBody();
    var button1 = Ext.widget('button', {
        text: 'Edit',
        handler: function (button) {
            console.log("button push");
        },
        floating: true,
        renderTo: body,
        style: 'position: absolute; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a border layout. define region:"east" like this.[image]

set east region opacity and modify CSS if needed.